# Laplace transform raised to a power

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

Suppose I have a function $F(s)$ which is the (two sided) laplace transform of some function $f(t)$.  Are there any statements I can make about $f(t)$ when I raise $F(s)$ to a positive power $\alpha$?

In perhaps nicer notation
$$
F(s) = \mathcal{B}\{f(t)\}
$$
$$
[F(s)]^{\alpha} = \mathcal{B}\{?\},\quad \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}
$$

I've tried a bunch of simple things already, but I just can't figure out a way of bringing the exponent $\alpha$ inside of the integral of the transform whenever $\alpha$ isn't an integer.